# SQL*plus does not tokenize its command-line arguments properly when the program path contains spaces

Tags: oracle, whitespace, sqlplus

I am using SQL*Plus with the following command line:

```
sqlplus user/pw@TNS @test.sql foo
```

The contents of `test.sql` follow:

```
SET VERIFY ON
DEFINE argone='&&1'
SELECT '&argone' FROM dual;
EXIT SQL.sqlcode
```

Results:

- When SQL*Plus executable is in `C:\Program Files\Oracle Client\whatever\sqlplus.exe` then `&&1` evaluates to `Files\Oracle`.
- When SQL*Plus executable is in `C:\Oracle\Client\10.2.xx\bin` then `&&1` evaluates to `foo`.

Did anyone encounter this problem and had a way to circumvent it?

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to use double quotes at both the command line and the `define` statement to properly capture the arguments with spaces.

Script:

```
SET VERIFY ON
DEFINE argone="&&1"
SELECT '&argone' FROM dual;
EXIT SQL.sqlcode
```

Command line:

```
sqlplus user/pw@TNS @test.sql "foo bar"
```